# Is there finer rate control for Postfix, e.g. 2/second?

Tags: postfix

I have managed to tune down postfix sending to one every second or one every five seconds. There's also an option to send only two or three concurrently.

Is there any way to send two every second or three every second?

Comment: Send what? 1/2/3 email(s) per user, per destination, per transport?

Comment: send maximum two emails per second to destination.